# Unexpected space in table

Tags: tables

I try to create a table in latex, however, the space between some columns is very unexpected.

Here is my working example:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
    \hline \hline
    & & The title of my table is long & &  \\ \hline \hline
     Criteria & M$_{1}$&  M$_{2}$ & M$_{3}$& M$_{4}$& M$_{5}$\\
    1 & 1400 & 1450& 300 &3340 & \\ 
    2 & & & & & \\
    3 & & & & & 
    \\ 
    \hline 
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

[image: Here is the output]

If the title of the table is short then, there is no problem.

Any help, please?

Comment: Consider using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The title of your table is considered as an element in Column 3. This is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \hline\hline
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{The title of my table is long}\\ 
        \hline\hline 
        Criteria & $M_1$ & $M_2$ & $M_3$ & $M_4$ & $M_5$ \\ 
        1        & 1400  & 1450  & 300   & 3340  & 0     \\
        2        &       &       &       &       &       \\
        3        &       &       &       &       &       \\
        \hline\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

As @DũngVũ has already pointed out in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462790/5001), the immediate cause of the problem is that you've assigned the string "The title of my table is long" to the third column of the six-column table. That third column is thus made as wide as is needed to display the title string.

One way to fix this issue is to let the title string span all 6 columns of the `tabular` environment, via a `\multicolumn{6}{c}{...}` directive. This method "works", but only if the width of the title string is less than the width of the remaining tabular material. A second, and in my view more robust fix starts off by recognizing that the title string is, structurally speaking, part of the title of the `table` and that it should not be placed inside the `tabular` environment. Instead, it should be placed inside the argument of `\caption`, and the `\caption` statement should likely be placed above rather than below the `tabular` material.

While you're at it, you may also want to improve the "look" of the table by replacing the `\hline` statements with `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` -- macros provided by the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package.

The following screenshot displays 3 tables: (1) the OP's original approach, (2) the fix achieved by using `\multicolumn`, and (3) the fix achieved by moving the title outside of the `tabular` environment (and using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]  %% OP's original code
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
    \hline \hline
    & & The title of my table is long & &  \\ 
    \hline \hline
    Criteria & M$_{1}$ & M$_{2}$ & M$_{3}$& M$_{4}$& M$_{5}$\\
    1 & 1400 & 1450& 300 &3340 & 4400  \\ 
    2 & & & & & \\
    3 & & & & & \\ 
    \hline \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label_1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]  %% using \multicolumn to fix the spacing issue
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
    \hline \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{The title of my table is long}\\ 
    \hline \hline
    Criteria & M$_{1}$&  M$_{2}$ & M$_{3}$& M$_{4}$& M$_{5}$\\
    1 & 1400 & 1450& 300 &3340 & 4400  \\ 
    2 & & & & & \\
    3 & & & & & \\ 
    \hline \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label_2}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]  %% using \caption and the macros of the booktabs package
    \caption{The title of my table}
    \label{tab:my_label_3}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *{6}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
    Criteria & M\textsubscript{1}&  M\textsubscript{2} & M\textsubscript{3}& M\textsubscript{4}& M\textsubscript{5}\\
    \midrule
    1 & 1400 & 1450& 300 &3340 & 4400  \\ 
    2 & & & & & \\
    3 & & & & & \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---